# Как сделать один модуль доступным для всех проектов солюшена?

Tags: .net

Модуль из проекта1 понадобился в проекте2. "Add existing item" так себе вариант, т.к. создает копию, придется редактировать два файла вместо одного. VS 12

Comment: В референс добавьте ссылку на Ваш проект в солюшене и импортируйте пространство имен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соберите свой модуль в библиотеку и подключите её к нужным проектам как референс.